# Java subtract array of time ranges from a parent time range

Tags: java-time

The time ranges (representing video lengths) are in Strings of this format: `HH:mm:ss`. Assume I have a parent time range that looks like this: `00:00:59` representing a video that is 59 seconds long.

I now have an array of time range pairs I must **remove** from the video because nothing interesting happened in the video during these time ranges. Eg input array:

```
[
00:00:10 to 00:00:20, 
00:00:30 to 00:00:35, 
00:00:35 to 00:00:40
]
```

I wish to remove these unimportant ranges from the 59 second video, and **calculate the remaining valid video segments**. In the above case the ideal output would be:

```
[
00:00:00 to 00:00:10, 
00:00:20 to 00:00:30, 
00:00:40 to 00:00:59
]
```

Comment: I'd not look for a library, but treat this as an algorithms exercise.

Comment: [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) and `LocalTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sort, iterate, and include

1. Sort the input intervals on their start time(to be excluded)
2. Iterate over each of the input interval to excluded
3. Include any interval between end of previous excluded interval and start of current excluded interval
4. At the end, check for any remaining interval by comparing with total length

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SequenceTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final SequenceTest sequenceTest = new SequenceTest();
        sequenceTest.computeIncludeIntervals(59,
            Arrays.asList((new int[][]{{10, 20}, {30, 35}, {35, 40}})));
        sequenceTest.computeIncludeIntervals(40,
            Arrays.asList((new int[][]{{10, 20}, {30, 35}, {35, 40}})));
        sequenceTest.computeIncludeIntervals(41,
            Arrays.asList((new int[][]{{10, 20}, {30, 35}, {35, 40}})));
        sequenceTest.computeIncludeIntervals(41,
            Arrays.asList((new int[][]{{0, 20}, {30, 35}, {36, 40}})));

    }

    protected List<int[]> computeIncludeIntervals(final int totalLength, List<int[]> excludeIntervals) {
        // sort the sequence by start time - O(NlogN)
        excludeIntervals.sort((a, b) -> a[0] == b[0] ? Integer.compare(a[1], b[1])
            : Integer.compare(a[0], b[0]));

        int previousEnd = 0; // initial state
        final List<int[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int[] exclude : excludeIntervals) {
            if (previousEnd < exclude[0]) {
                int[] include = new int[]{previousEnd, exclude[0]};
                result.add(include);
            }
            previousEnd = Math.max(previousEnd, exclude[1]);
        }

        // remaining tail
        if (previousEnd < totalLength) {
            result.add(new int[]{previousEnd, totalLength});
        }

        System.out.println("Total Length: " + totalLength + ", Input: " + excludeIntervals.stream()
            .map(interval -> interval[0] + ":" + interval[1])
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        System.out.println("Included: " + result.stream().map(interval -> interval[0] + ":" + interval[1])
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));

        return result;
    }
}
```

#### Actual solution

1. Write a transformer to transform input date time to epoch unix time
2. Use the above approach to compute include intervals
3. Transform include intervals in epoch time to date time using reverse transformer

Answer (score 2):

I wrote 2 classes:  TimeRange and TimeRangeSet.

**Usage:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException
{
    TimeRange minuend = new TimeRange("00:00:00", "00:00:59");
    
    TimeRangeSet subtrahendSet = new TimeRangeSet();
    
    subtrahendSet
        .addRange("00:00:10", "00:00:20")
        .addRange("00:00:30", "00:00:35")
        .addRange("00:00:35", "00:00:40");
        
    TimeRangeSet differenceSet = minuend.minus(subtrahendSet);
    
    System.out.println("\t " + minuend);
    System.out.println("minus\t" + subtrahendSet);
    System.out.println("equals\t" + differenceSet);
}
```

**Output:**

```
         00:00:00 to 00:00:59
minus   [00:00:10 to 00:00:20, 00:00:30 to 00:00:35, 00:00:35 to 00:00:40]
equals  [00:00:00 to 00:00:10, 00:00:20 to 00:00:30, 00:00:40 to 00:00:59]
```

**TimeRange:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.temporal.ValueRange;

public class TimeRange implements Comparable <TimeRange>
{
    private ValueRange valueRange;
    
    private static final SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            
    public TimeRange(ValueRange valueRange)
    {
        this.valueRange = valueRange;
    }
    
    public TimeRange(String fromTime, String toTime) throws ParseException
    {
        this
        (
            ValueRange.of(simpleDateFormat.parse(fromTime).getTime(), simpleDateFormat.parse(toTime).getTime())
        );
    }
    
    public TimeRangeSet minus(TimeRangeSet subtrahendSet)
    {
        TimeRangeSet difference = new TimeRangeSet();
        
        subtrahendSet.forEach
        (
            (subtrahend) ->
            {
                TimeRangeSet subDifference = new TimeRangeSet();
                subDifference.addAll(minus(subtrahend));
                difference.addAll(subDifference.minus(subtrahendSet));
            }
        );
        
        return difference;
    }
        
    public TimeRangeSet minus(TimeRange subtrahend)
    {
        TimeRangeSet difference = new TimeRangeSet();
        
        long A  = valueRange.getMinimum();
        long B  = valueRange.getMaximum();
        long C  = subtrahend.valueRange.getMinimum();
        long D  = subtrahend.valueRange.getMaximum();
        
                
        if ( B <= C )                                       //  A-----------B
            difference.addRange(ValueRange.of(A, B));       //              C-------D
        else
            
        if ( A >= D )                                       //          A-----------B
            difference.addRange(ValueRange.of(A, B));       //  C-------D
        else
            
        if ( (A >= C)  && (A < D) && (B > D) )              //  A---------------B
            difference.addRange(ValueRange.of(D, B));       //  C-------D                                               
        else
            
        if ( (A < C)  && (B > C) && (B <= D) )              //  A---------------B
            difference.addRange(ValueRange.of(A, C));       //          C-------D                   
        else
            
        if ( (A < C)  && (B > C) && (B > D) )               //  A---------------B
        {                                                   //      C-------D
            difference.addRange(ValueRange.of(A, C));
            difference.addRange(ValueRange.of(D, B));
        }
        
        return difference;
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%tT to %tT", valueRange.getMinimum(), valueRange.getMaximum());
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(TimeRange input)
    {
        return this.toString().compareTo(input.toString());
    }
}
```

**TimeRangeSet:**

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.temporal.ValueRange;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class TimeRangeSet extends TreeSet <TimeRange>
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TimeRangeSet addRange(ValueRange valueRange)
    {
        super.add(new TimeRange(valueRange));
        return this;
    }
    
    public TimeRangeSet addRange(String fromTime, String toTime) throws ParseException
    {
        super.add(new TimeRange(fromTime, toTime));
        return this;
    }
    
    public TimeRangeSet minus(TimeRangeSet subtrahendSet)
    {       
        subtrahendSet.forEach
        (
            (subtrahend) ->
                ((TimeRangeSet) this.clone()).forEach
                (
                    (minuend) ->
                    {
                        if (this.addAll(minuend.minus(subtrahend)))
                            this.remove(minuend);
                    }
                )
        );
        
        return this;
    }
}
```